# C++ lambda size

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

This is an example of a lambda class which cann call any lambda. It is intended to use as a functor.

```
template<class T>
struct lambda_class {
 T lambda;
 void operator()(){ lambda();}
};
```

Is there any size guarantee for this class. What I need is to store it inside a union but I cannot put this inside a union without a specific template argument. For that I need to know what the maximum size of a lambda is. It doesn't matter when it is compiler specific.

**Edit 1:**
Yes, my intention was to understand how std::function is implemented internally. For that reason I chose EASTL for understanding because it is quite well readable in comparison to the gnu libstdc++.

The following link contains the code for the function implementation which seems to use placement new only:
https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/internal/function.h

What I do not unterstand is why does that fit into the storage type? Line 131 and 141 contains the struct definition for the functor and the allocator. What happens when a lambda is bound with more than one captured variable?

Comment: _"which cann call any lambda"_ Are you sure about that? Wouldn't this require some variadic parameters and forwarding?

Comment: Why do you need to know the size to specify a template argument? There is no maximum, it is unbounded (ignoring compiler limitations).

Comment: Since a lambda can capture there is no limit on it's size except for what the machine can handle.

Comment: 1. See [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/). 2. Lambda size can vary from zero to any size, this depends on many factors, stating from context it is used to what variables lambda captures when it is used. 3. Why do you want to know this?

Comment: [You say "X", but I think you are concerned with "Y"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: That's not a class, it's a class template. You can't create instances of it anywhere. It looks like you're trying to recreate `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: Irrespective of the lambda's size, on the topic of "store it inside a union": don't. Not unless you are prepared to write a huge pile of ugly code that correctly implements the constructor and destructor semantics of objects that are stored in a union. This is a mandatory requirement that you cannot ignore, otherwise you get a nice little bundle of undefined behavior, as your reward. Instead of a union, use `std::variant`, which will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Very confusing title, so unclear question. Consider using genuine C++11 [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)-s or don't speak at all of "lambda"s. You should **edit your question** to improve it a lot (and add a few more paragraphs of motivation and context).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to want a `std::function<void()>`.

`std::function<void()>` can store any callable object (that can be called with 0 arguments) that can be copied and destroyed.  It either stores it in an internal buffer (large enough to store a function pointer), or on the heap (if it is too large).

It does this through a mechanism known as type erasure.

It isn't a lambda, but it can store lambdas.

Storing a non-POD C++ class inside a union is a bit of a pain.  Consider using a `boost::variant` or `std::variant` if you have [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support.

Solving this problem without `std::function` and `variant` I would qualify as hard, and a few steps beyond your skill level if you are at the point of wondering how to store a template (and not a template instance) as data.

Comment: My intention was to avoid heap usage. At the moment, this seems to be hard. With usage of heap memory it would be easy.

Comment: @Gustavo Ask the following question: "I want to have a `std::function<void()>` that does not use the heap. I am ok with it not working with all lambdas, but ideally I want it to break at build time if I use a too-large lambda." -- or, rather, try to write that, and come back with more questions when you run into problems.  Learn about type erasure, std function, std::aligned storage, placement new, etc.

Comment: Ok then the last question: Is it possible without using dynamic memory allocation? In my opinion it's not without knowing the maximum storage size of the functor object. When using heap I can use a base class and and a templatizes child class.

Comment: @Gustavo Yes, if you are willing to bound the max size/alignment of stored lambdas.  This can be checked at compile time so you get a build error if you try to store an over-sized lambda.  You can still use the virtual dispatch solution for type erasure, but I prefer to use a manual vtable solution for type erasure when working with SBO stored objects.